# Can I develop asp.net 3.5/2.0 projects using Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, compatibility

Can I develop asp.net 3.5/2.0 projects using Visual Studio 2010? Or I will be stick on .Net Framework 4.0?

Comment: I would think you would be able to develop 2/3.5 projects.  Would be pretty worthless if it wasn't backwards compatible at this point.

Comment: Do none of the answers satisfy your question?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From [MSDN VS 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/dd441784.aspx)

> The multi-targeting feature of Visual
>   Studio lets you specify the version of
>   the .NET Framework, or its profile,
>   that is required for your application.
>   The key benefit of multi-targeting is
>   that you can use the current version
>   of Visual Studio to create and develop
>   projects that target earlier versions
>   of the .NET Framework. For example,
>   you can continue to develop projects
>   that were created in Visual Studio
>   2008 without adding new .NET Framework
>   dependencies.

Comment: When you are using Unit Test projects, they will always be compiled to .NET 4.0 though.

Comment: True, but that is because you are using a framework 4.0 set of classes.

Comment: That's because of *what*? I've got a 3.5 solution that I can't test now, even with sp1.

Answer (score 20):

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can develop 2.0 and 3.5 ASP .NET projects, and other many other types of projects with Visual Studio 2010. When we built the multi-targeting support, we were especially sensitive to web development, because it wouldn't be realistic to expect that users would upgrade their servers immediately. In many cases, this wouldn't even be possible.

Answer (score 1):

I have a project developed in ver 3.5 using VS 2008.  I have now installed VS 2010 and when I go to open the project, the first screen says "Welcome to the Visual Studio Conversion Wizard" which says that the project must be converted.  So looks like Wally is correct - the files will be different even if the framework remains the same.

Answer (score 1):

Not if you use Unit Tests.

[image: Attempted re-targeting of the project has been canceled. You cannot change the specified .NET framework version or profile for a test project.]

Yes, SP1 is installed:
[image: Uninstall entry for VS2010sp1]

Answer (score -4):

No, you can't.  You can target framework versions, but the project/solution files are different. VS 2008 complains.  This is MS not being developer friendly.